# Error when download MINST database

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntax-error

I copied the code from the website of tensorflow. But meet a error here.
I check several others code and they havn't met yet. So i wonder if i mad something wrong.

Now i want to download and install the MNIST database file.  Should i download it from the web of MNIST first ?

If i do that, how can i make it be installed or be reconized by tensorflow?

```
def _read32(bytestream):
  File "<stdin>", line 11
    def _read32(bytestream):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: please show a few lines of code preceding and following.  it's a syntax error.    it likely has nothing t to with MNIST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some very useful information on setting up the MNIST data with TensorFlow is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). This tutorial will explain how to set up the MNIST database and run the tensorflow program in Python. It also explains the fundamentals of Tensorflow and the example that uses the MNIST data set.

[Edit]
After downloading the same example project from [GitHub](https://github.com/loliverhennigh/All-Convnet-TensorFlow-MNIST-Tutorial), I tried running the project with command (on Windows):

```
python all_conv_mnist.py
```

but I ran into other errors. So, I went to [the MNIST database site](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and downloaded all four .gz files at the top of the page, and moved them to the folder MNIST_data inside the project downloaded from GitHub (without extracting the .gz files). Then I ran the above command in the project folder, and success.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copy from google git.It seems the offical website from google. https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py

Comment: Do you have a url, or the file name this is from?

Comment: Cause in the cmd, the signal '>>>' is different from '...' . With an 'ENTER' button just ok. I have fixed it up. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you upvote/accept my answer please? Thanks.